# OS X login screen boots to mirrored mode bug

Tags: macos

My iMac pro is booting in mirrored mode when I don't even have that selected. If I do command + F1 it shows the extended desktop mode which is how it should be but this is only a temporary fix. I'm using a thunderbolt 3 to HDMI adapter for my 1080p television. I have reset PRAM and SMC to no avail. As well as fiddling around with the display settings. I also have tried disk repair and different orientations for the dual monitor setup. No luck. I had an iMac pro with the same exact set up and cables working not even a few weeks ago. Any ideas?